# Windows can access file, DOS file copy gets Access Denied

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems, command-prompt

I'm trying to set up a set of folders on a Windows NT server 2008 (yes, I know, old) where a user doesn't have access to see the list of files within the folder, but can read a file if they know the full file path.

So I've set up the following AD permissions:

```
Permissions on the containing folder ("This folder only"):
    Traverse folder / execute file
    Read attributes
    Read extended attributes
    Read permissions
Permissions on the files ("Files only"):
    Traverse folder / execute file
    List folder / read data
    Read attributes
    Read extended attributes
    Read permissions
```

... and from *windows*, everything looks great!  I can't see inside the folder, but if I know the full path to a file within, I can type it into an address bar and open the file.

But when I run in Command Prompt:

```
COPY "FullPathToSameFileAsBefore.txt" "C:\someLocalSpot.txt"
```

... I get:

```
Access is denied.
    0 file(s) copied.
```

Any ideas?  Is there some special access Command Prompt needs to perform the copy that windows doesn't in order to read the file?  Any alternatives that will work instead?  I can set any of the permissions that are needed, with the caveat that the user cannot see the list of files within the directory.

**EDIT with additional info:**

So I tried to perform a copy with VBScript using a FileSystemObject.  Same error.  But using VBScript to read the file with an ADODB binary stream *does* work.

So it seems to boil down to "You can read this file, but you can't perform a copy."  Which seems weird, since if you can *read* the file, you can certainly copy it (read it, then write the contents someplace else.)

Comment: If there are restrictions on the destination directory you will have the same error. Check you can create there with "echo test > c:\testlocation\test.txt"
And check you can get a directory listing of the source directory in DOS too.

Comment: @Buzby - nah, it's not a restriction on the output location.  I was able to copy a file from a different directory to the same output path/file without issue.

Comment: @Buzby - I changed the vbscript, instead of doing FSO.CopyFile, to use ADODB binary stream read/write, and it's able to read and then write the file.  Something about 'Copy' itself is tripping things up... which doesn't make a lot of sense to me